# When my code sorts the inputs, why doesn't it work in certain scenarios?

Tags: python, sorting, input

I am new to Python.
First, the code is supposed to take an input (in the form of "x/y/z" where x,y, and z are any positive integer) and split it into three different variables.

```
input = raw_input()
a, b, c = input.split("/", 2)
```

I want the second part of my code to take these three variables and sort them based on their numerical value.

```
order = [a, b, c]
print order
order.sort()
print order
```

While this works perfectly for most inputs, I have found that for inputs "23/9/2" and "43/8/2" the output has not been sorted so is not returned in the correct order. Any thoughts as to what could be causing inputs such as these to not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that you are sorting strings, and expecting them to be sorted like integers.  First convert your list of strings to a list of ints if you would like numerical sorting.

```
>>> sorted(['23', '9', '2'])
['2', '23', '9']
>>> sorted(map(int, ['23', '9', '2']))
[2, 9, 23]
```

Here is how you could rewrite your code:

```
input = raw_input()
a, b, c = map(int, input.split("/", 2))
order = [a, b, c]
print order
order.sort()
print order
```

If you need to convert them back to strings, just use `map(str, order)`.  Note that on Python 2.x `map()` returns a list and on 3.x it will return a generator.

Comment: +1 for a clear answer with good info.  @Zach, don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem. Keep the SO love train rollin'.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @JoeFish. SO told me that I had to wait 10 minutes before accepting an answer, and I stepped away from my computer for a bit too long.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting strings but you should be sorting integers. So you have to convert each string to an integer using `int`:

```
order = [int(a), int(b), int(c)]
```